# Invalid argument in c++ with Qt integration

Tags: c++, eclipse, qt

I'm trying to write a Qt program in eclipse with C++, but I can't get past an error:

```
void MyTests::populateFirstList(){
    Question* q = new Question;
    q = this->ctr->getCurrent();
    string s = this->ctr->toString(q);
}
```

Question is a type defined by me, and the line with toString(q) returns an error saying invalid arguments. 
The funcion toString():

```
string Controller::toString(Question* q){
    string s="";
    string text = q->getText();
    char c;
    string::iterator it;
    for (it= text.begin(); it != text.end(); it++)
    {
        if ((*it) == ' ') {
            s+="\n";
        }
        else {
            s+=it;
        }
    }
    return s;
}
```

And just to be safe, the function getCurrent():

```
Question* Controller::getCurrent(){
    return this->question;
}
```

I don't understand why this happens, because the function toString() should take a pointer to a Question, and q is one. I'm not even sure if the error is caused within these functions or somewhere deeper. Thanks for any help.

The error message is:

```
invalid arguments ' Candidates are:
    std::basic_string < char,std::char_traits < char >, std::allocator < char > >
      toString(Question *) '
```

Comment: 1. What IS an error ? 2. You allocate a memory with `Question* q = new Question;` and the next line kills a pointer to it: `q = this->ctr->getCurrent();`

Comment: **Exact** error message, please!

Comment: @borisbn I'm not sure what the first question is supposed to mean, and as for the second, q is a pointer all through this function, isn't it? Actually I'm quite confused regarding pointers.

Comment: Are you sure that type of `this->ctr` is exactly `Controller *` or some smart pointer to `Controller` ?

Comment: @borisbn yes, I'm sure.

Comment: Does Question have an implicit conversion operator to string? In any case you can simply use a cast to make explicit which toString() overload you want to call.

Answer (score 1):

Perform : Run QMake 
then build
:)

Comment: Still having the problem. I am trying to build an existing QT Windows application to Android.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually your error comes from line

```
        } else s+=it;
```

which eventually should be

```
        } else s+=*it;
```

This will probably not solve the question, but i do not see any QT in here. Why not make use of QT-Objects when writing a Qt-App?

```
void MyTests::populateFirstList(){
    Question* q = this->ctr->getCurrent();
    QString s = this->ctr->toString(q);
}


QString Controller::toString(Question* q){
    QString s;
    QString text = q->getText();
    s = text.replace(" ","\\n");
    return s;
}


Question* Controller::getCurrent(){
    return this->question;
}
```

Comment: This did not solve it. Also, I'm quite unfamiliar with Qt, and I would like to keep the use of it to a minimum. :)

Comment: i found 2 references to your error, one is a missing STL configuration for eclipse and one is a bug in the CDT Parser. Just from your code, given the types are correct, this looks good. You can try by disabling error parser and compile/run and see if it works. But generally if you want to work with QT do not avoid it :). I do not like the idea of mixing to many frameworks, so i only work on QT.